# Spring 3.1.1 web MVC - limit response to interface geters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

The following is a snippet from a project based on Spring web MVC 3.1.1. Json serialization is made via Jackson.

I have a controller which is mapped to a URL and everything is working fine.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/vod")
public class VODController {
 private Configuration configuration;
 private SearchAPI     searchAPI;

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "cmd=list")
 public @ResponseBody GetAssetsReply listVODAssets(long offset, int limit) {
    SearchVODAssetRequest searchVODAssetRequest = new SearchVODAssetRequest();
    //.... some irrelevant code
    return searchAPI.searchVODAssets(searchVODAssetRequest);
 }
}
```

And this is `GetAssetsReply`:

```
public class GetAssetsReply  {
    private long totalAssets;
    private List<VODAsset> assets = new LinkedList<VODAsset>();

    // Getters and setters removed for simplicity
}
```

`VODAsset` is an interface:

```
public interface VODAsset {
    public String getName();
}
```

And this is its implementation:

```
public class AssetElement implements VODAsset {
    private String     id;
    private String     name;
    private double     duration;

    // Getters and setters removed for simplicity
}
```

Finally to the question:
The controller returns me the expected result with one down side - It returns the VOD assets with its ID and duration in addition to its name. What I would expect is to get only the name due to the fact that the object is pointed by the above `VODAsset` interface.
How can I get this behavior? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you are using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for convert result to JSON, then you can use [org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.7/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) to avoid the field to be polupated into JSON result. (Henry) Furthermore, it is possible to add to the interface `@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)` which would cause Jackson not to search automatically for fields to serialize and then add `@JsonProperty` on the fields that are indeed needed for serialization (virtually implementing a white list scheme for the Jackson field serialization strategy).

Here is the sample code which solves the above problem:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE) //This tells the json serializer not to search for properties to serialize
public interface VODAsset {
    @JsonProperty //This tells the json serializer that this is a property that it should serialize
    public String getName();
}
```

On the other hand per-field ignore scheme can be implemented the following way:

> Marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is
>   to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization
>   functionality. That is, it should not be consider a "getter", "setter"
>   or "creator".

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have used 2 things: 1. I have added on the interface `@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)` 2. I have added on the interface's `getName` method `@JsonProperty` which effectively eliminated all other fields from the json serialization strategy. Should I edit your answer and accept it? don't know how it works.....

Comment: and yes, I didn't mention it on the question about Jackson. Nice catch :)

Comment: Drawback of this method is that you cannot have more than one "view" of the object. If you add a second interface that exposes more details, this details are shown on each occurence of the object.
Example: VODAsset implements getName() and exposes it via @JsonProperty. VODAssetDetail implements getName() and getId(), both exposed. This will always expose both properties regardles of if you return AssetElement as VODAsset or VODAssetDetail.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer (using @JsonProperty and @JsonIgnore) couples your data model to the specific use case, and if you ever need to return a different projection of this object (e.g. the id property) it would mean creating another class or changing the annotations and recompiling this class.

I usually prefer to return a map which I populate explicitly for every use case. e.g.

```java
Map<String, Object> responseBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
/*
JSON format: 
{
    "prop1":"<value1>",
    "edition":"<value2>",
    "dateProp":"<formatted date>"
}
*/
responseBody.put("prop1", value1);
responseBody.put("prop2", value2);
responseBody.put("dateProp", dateFormat.format(expirationDate));
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Natrually you can also use @ResponseBody instead of explicitly creating a ResposeEntity.

Comment: but then again, I would not need to use this very useful feature of returning whatever object I like (with @ResponseBody)

Comment: I to ended up creating maps to return subsets, or specializations of existing objects.

Answer (score 1):

I created a generic solution using delegating proxies. That solved multiple problems:

- you can have different interfaces on the same implementation which expose different details of the same object (e.g. IPersonList for collections, IPersonDetail which extends IPersonList for details.
- you don't need to use @Json... annotations in your entity classes

Example code (using commons-proxy):

```
/**
 * Wraps an object as delegating proxy, exposing only the methods of the interface
**/
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T> T wrap(Object sourceObject, Class<T> targetInterface)
{
    return (T) new ProxyFactory().createDelegatorProxy(
            new ConstantProvider(sourceObject),
            new Class[] {targetInterface});
}
```

Now you can use

```
return wrap(assetElement, VODAsset.class)
```

to get a "view" of type VODAsset of your element.

Next step would be to create an intercepting proxy that checks getter's return values. Of one is an interface, it has to create a proxy for the return value as well. Special handling for Lists is required too (e.g. for your example of a list of VODAsset). So you have to create the proxy recursively.

I did some performance tests by creating 1.000.000 proxies in a loop after creating 100 proxies as jvm "warmup":

- Java Reflection Proxies (Using ProxyFactory): ~1200ms
- CGLib Proxies (Using CglibProxyFactory): ~3900ms
- Javassist Proxies (Using JavassistProxyFactory): ~470ms

So using Javaasist as Proxy factory, the overhead of creating such proxies is moderate.

Comment: This looks very elegant. Next time I need to project data from an object I will be trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations, I.e., classes are returned based on your Spring bean config. If you want a different result, return a different implementation. So if AssetElement has props you don't want to expose, create aanother class that impls your interface and only returns that prop. Use that impl in your GetAssetsReply instead.